# putting image and text in a "scrollable box" for use with contextmenu

Tags: image, text, contextmenu

I am junior i C# coding, learned things in console output.
Now i am trying to understand the forms better and trying to make an app in windows form.

My goal is to do a foreach( do enumration) loop what is pinging some hosts from file.
This part i succeeded.

Now i want to present this in a form wiht the  next layout.

hostname(text)      ipadress(text)  
i want the line to be selectable for a contextmenu.

I tried to do it in a textbox, but no succes, so i wanted to try it in a richtextbox but i am not sure if this is the proper choice.
Does anyone know what kind of control i have to use to achieve my goal, and which methods i should use.

I am not asking for writing me the whole code, just help me to think in the right way.
Your help would be very appriciated.

thanks.

Comment: oh on the same line i want to add some images, one image of an host indcating that the host is reachable or not